# TreeMap Keys and Iteration in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, treemap

I am using `TreeMap` and it behaves strangely in the following code.

Here is the code :

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap
object TreeMapTest extends App{

  val mp = TreeMap((0,1) -> "a", (0,2) -> "b", (1,3) -> "c", (3,4) -> "f")
  mp.keys.foreach(println) //A
  println("****")
  mp.map(x => x._1).foreach(println) //B
}
```

As you can see the two print lines (A and B) should have printed the same thing but the result is as follows:

```
(0,1)
(0,2)
(1,3)
(3,4)
****
(0,2)
(1,3)
(3,4)
```

Why is this happening here? The interesting thing is even the IDE believes that one can use these two interchangeably and suggests the replacement.

Comment: I don't think the order of the `keys` is the issue. It seems like the first key is missing in the second example.

Comment: Ah, duh. Thanks. I assumed that was just an error in the question!

Answer (score 3):

Scala collection library generally tries to return the same kind of collection it starts with, so that e.g. `val seq: Seq[Int] = ...; seq.map(...)` will return a `Seq`, `val seq: List[Int] = ...; seq.map(...)` will return a `List`, etc. This isn't always possible: e.g. a `String` is considered to be a collection of `Char`, but `"ab".map(x => x.toInt)` obviously can't return a `String`. Similarly for `Map`: if you `map` each pair to a non-pair, you can't get a `Map` back; but you map each pair to a pair `(Int, Int)`, and so Scala returns `Map[Int, Int]`. So you can't get both `(0, 1)` and `(0, 2)`: they would be duplicate keys.

To avoid this problem, convert your map to `Seq[((Int, Int), String)]` first: `mp.toSeq.map(x => x._1)` (or `mp.keySet.toSeq`).

Comment: Interesting, shouldn't compiler threw a warning for this situation? it's just something that people can get wrong

Comment: How would you differentiate it from situations where this is intended (e.g. `map.map { case (k, v) => (k, v + 1) }`)? Obviously, `Map#map` can't just be removed; you could try to argue for its deprecation, but I wouldn't expect success.